# Do something if one number is close to another number in VB6?

Tags: vb6, if-statement

Say I have 2 numbers, 5550, and 5650, and I want to know if these two numbers are close, within 200 of each other. How could I do this with VB6? I am clueless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply subtract the larger number (5650) from the smaller number (5550) and check if the result is less than your range (200).  I use `Abs` so you don't need to check which number is greater.

```
Dim number1 As Integer = 5550
Dim number2 As Integer = 5650
Dim range As Integer = 200

If Abs(number1 - number2) <= range Then
    ' Here is where your numbers are within 200.
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

```
If Abs(number1 - number2) < 200 Then
    'do something
EndIf
```

Warning: this will not handle integer overflow very nicely.  If number1 is a very large negative number and number2 is a large positive number, this may produce strange results.